# How can I make payment using credit/debit cards using PayPal payment gateway in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently using **paypal-rest-sdk** and want to accept payment using the cards.

In both sdk's (paypal rest and paypal checkout), when I create an order, in response there is an approve URL:

```
  {
    "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnowtoken=token", 
    "rel":"approve",
    "method":"GET"
  }
```

Which will take you to this page:

[image]

The payment with PayPal account (logging in) is working, it correctly redirects to the return URL.
However, the "Pay with Credit or Debit card" option is not working.

[image]

After filling the card information when I click on continue button a loading screen appears and nothing happens after that.

I have seen solutions using PayPal smart-buttons, but can it work using "Pay with Credit or Debit card" option?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "paypal-rest-sdk" ?  The PayPal-Node-SDK is deprecated, do not use it for anything. Use the current Checkout-NodeJS-SDK.

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server